# Is the powerset of every Dedekind-finite set Dedekind-finite?

Tags: set-theory, category-theory, axiom-of-choice, infinity

Is the powerset of every Dedekind-finite set Dedekind-finite?

I think this statement can be written in $\textbf{Set}$: If every mono (=injection) $f: A \to A$ is iso (=bijection), then every mono $g: 2^A \to 2^A$ is iso.

(Please edit if necessary)

Does the answer depend on some Choice principle?

Off-hand I don't see a referent to this. The Wikipedia entry for [Dedekind-infinite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set) only states that the powerset of a D-infinite set is D-infinite. (I tried searching Math.SE with the obvious keywords and faced ~5k entries).

Comment: Tip for searching the site, use (for example) `+Dedekind +finite +power [axiom-of-choice]` for a refined search which includes all the terms and posts in the tag [axiom-of-choice].

Comment: @AsafKaragila, ok great thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No: Suppose $X$ is infinite. Then there is a surjection from the collection $Fin(X)$ of finite subsets of $X$ onto $\omega$, namely, $Y\mapsto|Y|$. Since $Fin(X)\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$, we get a surjection from $\mathcal P(X)$ onto $\omega$.

But if there is a surjection $\varphi$ from $A$ onto $B$, then there is an injection from $\mathcal P(B)$ into $\mathcal P(A)$, namely $Y\mapsto \varphi^{-1}(Y)=\{a\in A\mid \varphi(a)\in Y\}$.

In particular, $\mathcal P(\omega)$ (and therefore $\omega$) injects into $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(X))$ for any infinite set $X$. That is to say that $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(X))$ is always either finite, or D-infinite.

On the other hand, it is consistent that there are D-finite infinite sets $A$ such that $\mathcal P(A)$ is also D-finite. For example, any *amorphous* set $A$ is like this. Recall that $A$ is amorphous iff it is infinite but any subset of $A$ is either finite, or has finite complement in $A$.

The reason here is that if $A$ is amorphous, then there is no surjection from $A$ onto $\omega$. But one can check that the following are equivalent for any $X$:

- $\omega$ injects into $\mathcal P(X)$,
- $X$ surjects onto $\omega$.

So, if $A$ is amorphous, $\mathcal P(A)$ is D-finite. See this blog [post](http://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2012/11/15/dedekind-infinite-power-sets/) of mine for this result, due to Kuratowski.

Comment: Alternately, Andres illustrated the proof of that last result in his fine answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139708/given-an-injection-mathbbn-to-mathcalpx-how-can-we-construct-a-surject).

Comment: Out of curiosity, Andres, "D-finite=finite" is a strictly stronger principle than "there are no amorphous sets", isn't it? So it's still consistent that there are infinite D-finite sets $A$ with $\mathcal{P}(A)$ D-finite, even if there aren't any amorphous sets?

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes, this is consistent. In the "Consequences of the axiom of choice" book, form 64 is "There are no amorphous sets", and form 82 is "$\mathcal P(X)$ is Dedekind-infinite for any infinite $X$". So we want a model where 64 holds and 82 fails. The book lists some examples.

Comment: @Cameron: As I wrote, in Cohen's first model the power set of an infinite set is Dedekind-infinite. This is inconsistent with the existence of an amorphous set, as the power set of an amorphous set is Dedekind-finite.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, curious why you refer to $\omega$ as opposed to $\mathbb N$? I thought $\omega$ denotes an ordinal, but don't see how that comes into play.

Answer (score 5):

The following is implicit in the answers given by Andres and Asaf, but it looks simpler, so it might be worthwhile to make it explicit.  Let $X$ be any infinite set, possibly Dedekind-finite.  Let $F$ be the function with domain $\omega$ defined by assigning to each natural number $n$ the family of all $n$-element subsets of $X$.  Then $F$ is a one-to-one function from $\omega$ into $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(X))$, the power set of the power set of $X$.  So if $X$ is D-finite, then either $X$ itself or $\mathcal P(X)$ is a D-finite set with D-infinite power set.

Comment: Hi Andreas. I should have said something about this. Yes, $F$ is the function one obtains when combining the two stages I described, and usually this is how the result is presented. But I feel that this "breaking" $F$ into stages helps me (one?) understand better what is happening, and lends itself to generalizations.

Comment: (And let me further add that we get more this way, not just injecting $\omega$ but $\mathcal P(\omega)$ into $\mathcal P^2(X)$.)

Answer (score 4):

Not without some choice. In fact if the power set of every D-finite set is D-finite, then there are no infinite D-finite sets.

It follows from the following results:

1. If $f\colon X\to\omega$ is surjective, then $\mathcal P(X)$ is D-infinite.

   To see that this holds, note that $n\mapsto\{x\in X\mid f(x)=n\}$ is an injection from $\omega$ into $\mathcal P(X)$, and this is an equivalent condition to D-infiniteness.
2. If $X$ is infinite then $\mathcal P(X)$ can be mapped onto $\omega$.

   To see this holds we can use the map: $A\mapsto\begin{cases} 0 & A\text{ infinite}\\ |A| &\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$ is surjective because $X$ is infinite.

Now it follows, if $X$ is an infinite D-finite set, either $\mathcal P(X)$ is D-infinite and we are done; or $\mathcal P(X)$ is D-finite and can be mapped onto $\omega$, therefore $\mathcal{P(P(}X))$ is the power set of a D-finite set, and is D-infinite.

---

Some consistency remarks:

1. It is consistent that there are no infinite Dedekind-finite sets which cannot be mapped onto $\omega$. For example in Cohen's first model.
2. It is consistent that there infinite Dedekind-finite sets which cannot be mapped onto $\omega$. For example in models where there is an amorphous sets (sets which cannot be written as a disjoint union of two infinite sets).
3. The axiom "Every countable $\cal A$ of non-empty sets has an infinite $\cal B\subseteq A$ such that $\prod\cal B\neq\varnothing$", which is weaker than countable choice proper, implies that every D-finite is finite, so it implies that the power set of a D-finite set is D-finite.

Comment: Thanks Asaf, +1. I accepted Andres' answer but could have gone with yours too. Question: "consistent" here means w.r.t $ZF$?

Comment: Yes, of course. Everything is relative to the consistency of ZF.

Comment: The "reverse mathematics" folks don't have a say in that? What about the constructivists? I'm searching for the universal.

Comment: Well, I'm not in reverse mathematics.

Comment: There's a conversation b/w Turing and Wittgenstein. One of them - I think LW - says that the game of chess is arbitrary, but the study of chess is not. I'm tempted to say that the behavior of infinite spaces is arbitrary, even if their study isn't.

Comment: I dislike Wittgenstein's approach to mathematics. Being a nihilist I can't say that mathematics is anymore meaningful than a politician's promises, but then again -- nothing is meaningful to begin with. This really crosses the line into philosophy, and I don't want to debate that. I also noted that you have the tendency to quote people whose philosophy towards mathematics is very constructive, and sometimes dismiss completely all the non-constructive parts of mathematics. I can't say that I agree with this attitude, and I can't say I like it either. I'm just tired of arguing about it...

Comment: I'm trained in control engineering, not philosophy. I see software running the world, and they're finite state machines, even if they do so by approximating uncountable state spaces - which makes me wonder what aspects of non-constructive math are applicable. You have such and such a residue around a pole in the complex plane and it determines a filter's characteristics. In what way is that constructive or non-constructive?

Comment: On the other hand there are recent books like http://www.amazon.com/Not-Even-Wrong-Failure-Physical/dp/0465092764 and http://www.amazon.com/The-Trouble-With-Physics-Science/dp/061891868X. Be mindful that the relation between math and reality can often diverge - in the past, most mathematicians were also scientists and engineers - up to, say, mid 20th century. But today, most mathematicians seem to work completely separately from science.

Comment: But why should mathematics be applicable to things?

Comment: To distinguish it from playing chess, which is not applicable to anything.

Comment: The beauty of mathematics is the fact that it's ideal. It's perfect. The physical world is coarse, grotesque and as far from perfection as humanly imaginable. I don't see any reason to wish for an interaction between mathematics and the real world.

Comment: First of all, with ZFC, there's no 3-dimensional geometry. This sounds ideal to you?

Comment: How is it that there is no 3-dimensional geometry in ZFC? I thought you can formalize and model geometry within set theory. Also, yes. I have zero geometrical thinking. If it's in 3-dimensions or less I usually have a hard time visualizing it. Strangely enough, if it's paradoxically counterintuitive in some non-Hausdorff topology -- that I can visualize.

Comment: Herrlich's *AC*, 5.2 "Disasters in geometry": "The paradoxical decompositions, unearthed by Hausdorﬀ, Banach and Tarski by means of the Axiom of Choice, demonstrate that in $\mathbb{R}^3$ even such functions describing the volume of bounded bodies do not exist"

Comment: @alancalvitti: I see. So because of the Banach-Tarski paradox, which is completely dissolved if you only discuss measurable sets, **ALL GEOMETRY IS INVALID FOREVER!** in ZFC? That's nonsense. That's taking up one single issue and blowing it up. As I keep pointing out, if we insist that all sets are Lebesgue measurable then we can partition the real numbers into more parts than points. Does **that** make more sense to you? Taking a set and slicing it up into strictly *more* non-empty parts than points? I don't know, I think it's weirder than the BT theorem.

Comment: Richard Feynman tells a story about how BT was posed to him as slicing an orange and making it as big as the sun, and he said, no because eventually you have indivisible atoms. So that's physical reality - no transitive closure. But in ZFC, non-measurable sets exist (unlike ZF+AD). Since Klein, geometry is defined as the study of isometry invariance. Isn't this is problem for ZFC?

Comment: But this is only a problem if you want the theory to exactly describe all that is physical. This is not what we want from a mathematical theory.

Comment: It's interesting: Hilbert wrote that there is no difference between the methods of physics and methods of geometry. But  there's a radical difference between the behavior of the real line in ZF+AD vs. ZFC, as you point out (with consequences in algebra, analysis as well). The methods of set theory seem unrelated to physics or geometry. I wish we could interview Brouwer on EM and Poincare' on tolerance spaces.

Comment: It becomes really difficult to discuss with you. You always do this thing with namedropping. Let's interview Hitler about what he thinks of the fact that there are many Jewish mathematicians. Maybe he'll tell us it's a scheme by the inferior race, or something raving mad like that. I don't care what other people think about mathematics, certainly not what people who died almost a century ago and did not witness the abstraction jump that occurred in the past century. [cont...]

Comment: (...)  You remind me of a crank which argued with me on this site, he wanted to formalize something in ZFC (a "contradiction") but refused to accept that the real numbers can be written as the union of singletons. You can't accept (even momentarily) some concept if you also accept its rejection. Either agree that you're an ultrafinitist, or that mathematics must be 100% relevant to the real world, or that you can accept that infinite objects have strange properties, and as such they do not correlate to physical things.

Comment: What means ultrafinite - beyond finite?

Comment: Ultrafinitism concerns itself with "manageable" numbers, there is no precise and canonical definition, but it is usually taken to be things which can be measured in the physical world. So for example $2^{1000}$ is a meaningless expression in this aspect because we cannot measure such number. I pointed you to Zeilberger before, he's a striking example for an ultrafinistist, and he stated that he believes that there is a largest natural number - it's just much larger than anyone can feasibly imagine.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144008/equivalences-to-d-finite-finite) for some equivalences to that statement (and hopefully, an answer to your question). In particular, it's equivalent to the (very weak) choice principle "D-finite=finite".